# Extracting outdated data when webscraping yahoo finance

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the price/change rate of stocks on yahoo finance. I have made a program that searches on google for the yahoo finance link of the stock i am interested in, and then extracts the data from the webpage. Problem is that it extracts data that are a couple of minutes old. The way the html request is programmed currently is so I can see the price, change rate, and when the data was last updated. I am quite new to programing so the answer might be pretty obvious, but I don't understand why it isn't extracting the current information.

Here is the code:

```
from googlesearch import search
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_data(stock):
   # Search for the yahoo finance website on Google
    url = ""
    for results in search(f"yahoo finance {stock} stock", tld='com', num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
        page = results.split('.')
        if page[1] == "yahoo":
           url = results
           break

    # Extract data
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    change = soup.find('div', {'class': 'D(ib) Mend(20px)'}).text 

    return change


print(get_data("apple"))
```

I have tried to find anything related to my problem but haven't found any solutions or what the problem might be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post also an example url.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Needed to specify the user-agent in the http request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).